# How do I use yes with e2fsck?

Tags: linux, e2fsck

I have tried the following with both LinuxMint 13 Cinnamon 32 bit and Trisquel 7.0 Gnome 32 bit and get the same error message:

```
$ yes | sudo e2fsck /dev/sdax
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
e2fsck: need terminal for interactive repairs
```

In each case, the partition /dev/sdax was **not** mounted.

Is it not possible to use yes with e2fsck?

Comment: `yes - output a string repeatedly until killed` what is the reason to use it here?

Comment: Based on the error message, I guess it insists on a terminal. Could you trick it in order to be able to use `yes` with it? Maybe, but you don't need to: it already has a `-y` option that does the same thing.

Comment: @Costas: I'd much rather have a program keep feeding 'y' to e2fsck than having to type it over and over again when there are file system errors.

Answer (score 22):

If [you are sceptical](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180036/how-do-i-use-yes-with-e2fsck/183955#comment300353_180043) whether `e2fsck -y` works for you next time, coins might help.

[image]

*I used to use this trick when there were no `yes` or `-y` or equivalent options in MS-DOS.*

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
sudo e2fsck -y /dev/sdax
```

Comment: The first solution is exactly equivalent to the nonworking example in the question (other than outputting "yes" instead of "y," which won't make any difference in this case).

Comment: Yes, I have expected that but I couldn't check it on my drive. But sometimes small details make difference.

Comment: In the future, I'll try

e2fsck -y /dev/sdax

but really won't know if it does what I want until the next time I have file system errors and e2fsck repeatedly asks me if I want to perform its suggested fixes.

e2fsck can suggest a lot of fixes when a file system is messed up; I just don't want to type 'y' over and over again when there are lots of errors.

Comment: this answer is too short and is not adding anything to the previous answer

Comment: but "the previous" answer is younger...

Answer (score 2):

i had to enter "n" (don't abort) before "yes", so i used `script`:

`(echo n; yes) | script --return -c "e2fsck /dev/sda1"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try also:

`sudo e2fsck -p /dev/sdax`

See `man e2fsck` for [description of all arguments](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/e2fsck.8.html).

Comment: This is *something*, but it’s not what the question is asking for.