# How can I make e2fsck non interactive?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, e2fsck

When I run "e2fsck" command through cli it asks for options like asking for abort, force rewrite etc, and the process get completed successfully. But I want to run "e2fsck" command using apache by executing this command through a bash script, from here I cannot pass these arguments. I have tries using -a, -p arguments the don't work. The closest solution that worked was from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/487438/563769 , it successfully passed n to abort but cannot pass yes to all others.

Comment: Use `-p` (safer) or `-y` (answer "yes" to any questions it may have been asking interactively). And read `man e2fsck` finally, it describes it all.

Comment: Did you check the first answer? `e2fsck -y ....`

Comment: And run e2fsck non-interactively is very unwise (IMHO)

Comment: Not considering that it is already strange to run it from the script commanded by Apache.

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation: `man e2fsck`